# Unable to get transaction hash and index of the UTXO to spend

Tags: transaction

We are unable to get transaction hash and index of the UTXO to spend. Actually we are creating simple transaction and were using this link https://developers.cardano.org/docs/stake-pool-course/handbook/create-simple-transaction

but we are not getting transaction hash and index of the UTXO to create draft transaction. Please help us to resolve it and give me any suggestion to sort out it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you not getting it? What error are you receiving and what command are you executing?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like cardano-cli isn't running properly for you, so lets start with something simple to prove that it is working.

Can you successfully run '**cardano-cli --version**' and get the version number?

Also, as others have mentioned here, '**cardano-cli query utxo --address $(cat payment.addr) --mainnet**' is all you need to list the details.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick response.

I am using below command but not getting any output. How could we create Draft the transaction without transaction hash and index of the UTXO. Please help me.

cardano-cli query utxo --address $(cat payment.addr) --mainnet

Thanks.

Comment: sorry my english is not so great and i loose it a bit your question. 1. i asked you please for an error message, 2. the "$(cat payment.addr) " , is that file in the same folder you are executing the command? 3. can you replace the "$(cat payment.addr)" with your address? and let us know if you still have an issue. last but not least :) if any question helps you, please vote with the upper arrow :)

Comment: Yes, payment.addr file in in the same folder from where we are shooting above command nor we are getting any error to run the command even we try to put direct address in the command but same result not getting any output. Output is coming blank without any error.

Comment: Please use reply within threads instead of creating new answer to the post, so that it's easier for you to answer respective queries (you have currently - possibly unknowingly - overlooked other questions). This is also easier for an onlooker to follow the flow of post

Comment: Okay, I am still struggling. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, payment.addr file in in the same folder from where we are shooting above command nor we are getting any error to run the command even we try to put direct address in the command but same result not getting any output. Output is coming blank without any error

Thanks.